# 3D Graph Network Topology Visualization: Lengthy Time to Build Graph Visualizer

Tags: graph, visualization, splunk

I found this app in Splunkbase called [3D Graph Network Topology Visualization](https://splunkbase.splunk.com/app/4611/) ([GitHub link](https://github.com/splunk/splunk-3D-graph-network-topology-viz)) and I've added it to my Splunk environment.

I'm performing a simple search for a large amount of data and using this visualization tool. However, the visualization tool sometimes takes large amounts of time to load the final results. So I did some discovery.

Here is my SPL

```
index=test source=mysource 
| dedup myaddress myneighboraddress 
| stats values(vendor), count by myaddress, myneighboraddress 
| table myaddress myneighboraddress count
```

**Edit** I've taken @warren suggestions (below) and updated my search. Although this does improve my search time, I don't believe the core issue was with my search.

```
index=test source=mysource
| fields - _raw
| fields myaddress myneighboraddress vendor
| stats values(vendor) as vendor count by myaddress, myneighboraddress
```

After checking the Job Inspector, I've noticed my search only takes from 1 second up to 5 seconds. However, depending on the total events I return (using the splunk `head` command), I noticed lengthy load times for the visualization to actually display anything. After my search is complete, and while the visualization is trying to process the graph, my browser will also bring the popup saying "Page Unresponsive: you can wait for it to becomes responsive or exit the page. Do you want to Wait?" because of how long the process is taking.

I've read the README and confirmed my `chrome://gpu` has "Hardware accelerated" turned on entry WebGL. Additionally, I confirmed my `chrome://settings` has the option "Use hardware acceleration when available" enabled. I have noticed when my search is complete, and the visualizer is trying to finish processing, my GPU will go to near 0% until everything is officially loaded in (but still choppy with dropped frame rate). I know there is [a ticket for this](https://github.com/splunk/splunk-3D-graph-network-topology-viz/issues/5), but it was last updated in 2020.

So my questions are:

1. Are there certain bench marks for hardware?
2. How dependent on a good GPU is the visualization to build out the graph?
3. Are there benchmarks on total events/nodes for the visualization results posted somewhere? I've seen the example images provided on the ReadMe that show approx 2k and 6k total events. Is anything above 10k events/nodes out of the question?
4. Are there any ways to speed up the initial loading of the visual results after a search has been performed?

I've performed my own benchmark tests, and would like to know if this is normal or if I'm doing something incorrect. My test is based entirely when my search is completed and right as the visualizer starts to process the graph. So I will use `| head X` at the end of my search (shown above) where X is my number below column 1:

| `head` of X (total nodes) | Total seconds to load (after search completes) |
| --- | --- |
| 20,000 | 42 |
| 15,000 | 21 |
| 10,000 | 12 |
| 8,000 | 10 |
| 6,000 | 7 |
| 5,000 | 4.7 |
| 4,000 | 2.5 |

Comment: What does your SPL look like? What mode is it running in? Without at least those details, pointing you in the proper direction is going to be very hard

Comment: index=test source=mysource
| dedup myaddress myneighboraddress
| stats values(vendor), count by myaddress, myneighboraddress
table myaddress myneighboraddress count

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, it seems the simple answers (at the time of this post) are the following:

1. There are no benchmarks (that can be found)
2. Even though the GPU acceleration was enabled in my browser, its unclear benchmarks for specific GPU hardware
3. There are no benchmarks posted anywhere to assist it total nodes the app can display (in a reasonable time)
4. Unknown on how to boost loading time of the visual

Answer (score 1):

See if this simplified version helps you at all (`dedup` is rarely the proper tool to use, and is almost always pointless to run before `stats` in the manner you're doing it):

```
index=test source=mysource vendor=* myaddress=* myneighboraddress=*
| fields - _raw
| fields myaddress myneighboraddress vendor
| stats count by myaddress myneighboraddress
```

Depending on the size of events, dropping `_raw` can be a huge performance improver. Likewise to only keeping the fields you care about

I removed the `values(vendor)` since your `| table` was immediately removing it

If you want it left in, do this `stats` line instead:

```
| stats values(vendor) as vendors count by myaddress myneighboraddress
```

Comment: Thanks for your post. Any reason why you have vendor=* (along with myaddress and myneighboraddress). Does including that in your search change anything? Doing a test, I didn't notice anything. Overall, this does decrease my the search time by a lot (so thanks for that, I'll keep that dedup bit you mentioned in mind), but that doesn't seem to be the core issue with the visual graph that displays the 3D nodes. Once again, after the search has completed, the visual graph takes an incredibly long time to load the results. I'm still left with my 4 questions at the bottom of my post.

Comment: @StudiousProgrammer - if you know all three fields will be in the events you care about, Splunk will return results faster by being more specific. If, however, those fields don't always exist in every event, it's better to leave them out of the first search, and instead collect them with `stats`

Comment: My issue isn't with my search. I've updated my question, and perhaps that will resolve any confusion. I found an app in Splunkbase called 3D Graph Network Topology Visualization and I've added it to my Splunk environment. It's this app's graphs that take a long time to load. I'm trying to find the limits for this app alone. My Splunk searches are not the issue (or shouldn't be as they complete very quickly). But within the context of the graphs I'm using from this app, they take long times to load. See my changes in my question for a break down I tested.

Comment: @StudiousProgrammer - from the wording of the original question, it sounded like the search was causing the visualization to run poorly. If it's an *app* problem, you'll [most likely] need to contact Splunk Works, or, maybe, submit a pull request at GitHub.